# Select the smallest value from all the repeated elements of a list

Tags: prolog

An example will explain better what I'm trying to do.
For example, I have this prolog list:

```
L=[(d,15),(e,16),(g,23),(e,14),(h,23),(d,19)]
```

And I want to generate this list:

```
L'=[(d,15),(g,23),(e,14),(h,23)]
```

This is, from all occurrences of element (X,_), leave the one with the smallest Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really elegant but... what about the following code?

```
getFirst((X, _), X).

isMinor(_, []).

isMinor((X1, Y1), [(X2, _) | T]) :-
  X1 \= X2,
  isMinor((X1, Y1), T).

isMinor((X, Y1), [(X, Y2) | T]) :-
  Y1 =< Y2,
  isMinor((X, Y1), T).

purgeList(_, [], []).

purgeList(X1, [(X2, Y2) | Tin], [(X2, Y2) | Tout]) :-
  X1 \= X2,
  purgeList(X1, Tin, Tout).

purgeList(X, [(X, _) | Tin], Tout) :-
  purgeList(X, Tin, Tout).

filterList([], []).

filterList([H1 | Tin1], [H1 | Tout]) :-
  isMinor(H1, Tin1),
  getFirst(H1, X),
  purgeList(X, Tin1, Tin2),
  filterList(Tin2, Tout).

filterList([H1 | Tin], Tout) :-
  \+ isMinor(H1, Tin),
  filterList(Tin, Tout).
```

From

```
filterList([(d,15),(e,16),(g,23),(e,14),(h,23),(d,19)], L)
```

I obtain (`L` is unified with)

```
[(d,15),(g,23),(e,14),(h,23)]
```

Comment: Not elegant, but that's what I wanted and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also write:

```
select_elements(L,Lout):-        
  sort(L,L1),
  reverse(L1,L2),
  remove(L2,L3),
  output_list(L,L3,Lout).

remove([],[]).
remove([H],[H]).
remove([(X,Y1),(X,Y2)|T],[(X,Y1)|T1]):-remove([(X,Y2)|T],T1).
remove([(X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)|T],[(X1,Y1)|T1]):-
       dif(X1,X2),\+member((X2,_),T),
       remove([(X2,Y2)|T],T1).
remove([(X1,Y1),(X2,_)|T],[(X1,Y1)|T1]):-
       dif(X1,X2),member((X2,_),T),
       remove(T,T1).


output_list([],_,[]).
output_list([H|T],L,[H|T1]):-member(H,L),output_list(T,L,T1).
output_list([H|T],L,T1):- \+member(H,L),output_list(T,L,T1).
```

Example:

```
?- select_elements([(d,15),(e,16),(g,23),(e,14),(h,23),(d,19)],L).
L = [ (d, 15), (g, 23), (e, 14), (h, 23)] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
test((V, N), Y, Z) :-
    (  member((V,N1), Y)
    -> (  N < N1
       -> select((V,N1), Y, (V,N), Z)
       ;  Z = Y)
    ;   append(Y, [(V,N)], Z)).

my_select(In, Out) :-
    foldl(test, In, [], Out).
```

For example

```
 ?- my_select([(d,15),(e,16),(g,23),(e,14),(h,23),(d,19)], Out).
Out = [(d,15),(e,14),(g,23),(h,23)] ;
false.
```